# Do HVAC technicians need to be registered or licensed?

Tags: hvac, furnace

We had several HVAC companies come out on a Sunday to look at our furnace. Unfortunately, it could not be fixed. Each contractor offered their solution and did not charge us for their time- but if they had to fix it it would be more because it was Sunday. Everyone was consistent and up front about the fees.

However, one contractor demanded $225 for a 10 minute chat; if we used him he would deduct the amount. My question, is this legal? What license, registration, etc is required to do this job? In reflection, my husband realized that the guy asked what the other contractors had said and he would than reaffirm their diagnosis. Looking for feedback. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a contract with him?

Comment: No we do not have a contract with him.

Comment: No invoice. Just wanted money.

Comment: You seem to be asking two different questions. Is your post about refundable consulting fees or licensing?

Comment: Licensing. I guess it is sort of a two fold question. I am more interested to know about licensing.

Comment: Then you'd want to edit your post to tell us where you are and what licensing authorities are involved.

Comment: I see 2 different trains of thought on this, if I was called to do an emergency repair that is a call that can be charged for even if the unit was not repairable. But if called for a quote on updating a system that would be different some do charge for quotes but take it off when they get the job, most don't charge for quotes. But it sounds like an emergency call was made so there could be a charge without a contract.

Comment: Two viable answers up there. How about dropping them into place, fellas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because licensing and legal questions are off-topic

Comment: Do you mean to ask "Do I have to pay $225 for what I thought was a free estimate?"

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 different trains of thought on this, if I was called to do an emergency repair that is a call that can be charged for even if the unit was not repairable. But if called for a quote on updating a system that would be different some do charge for quotes but take it off when they get the job, most don't charge for quotes. But it sounds like an emergency call was made so there could be a charge without a contract. But yes contractors need to be licensed and for hvac also need an EPA license called 608 1, 2 or 3 if they have all 3 it is called a universal license, but a 609 license is also required for motor vehicles to be able to do everything.

Answer (score 0):

**Licensing** for technical trades (plumbing, electrical, HVAC, roofing, etc.) is generally about making sure that the contractors have the background/training/knowledge to do the job in a safe & effective manner.

Secondary to that is often issues of ensuring that they have proper insurance and after that comes "business" issues.

In most places that I know of, the actual fees charged are entirely up to the business & the consumer - for example, a particular job could be time & materials or could be a flat fee, all open to negotiation between the parties. Never heard of a "must have free consult" rule.

When you call someone in at odd times - e.g., nights & weekends - it is often expected that the fees, whether for work or consulting, may be significantly higher than normal. Any honest tradesman will be upfront about this.

I once had an HVAC problem one time on December 25, but my regular guy was available and we agreed on a price for a quick consult with the understanding that if he needed any parts that he didn't have on his truck, I'd be out of luck. But it worked out great - for $100 he figured out what was likely the problem and told me what to get and I was able to get it the next day and install it myself (except when dealing with gas, HVAC repairs today aren't much different from computer repairs). But there was never any idea of "sure I'll take a look for free" even though there have been other times when he has given me free estimates for jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Most furnaces can't be fixed.  That's because fixing furnaces is tedious, skilled work involving low cost parts with poor markup, with a high chance of go-backs and dissatisfied customers. Whereas a new furnace is simple, straightforward work, with good markups, and the manufacturer backing you up for warranty claims in the event of go-backs.

Even worse, if you fail to fix the furnace, he'll be dissatisfied and won't buy the new furnace from you.  Much smarter to position yourself to be the one who makes the commish on the furnace, so make the ask: talk him into writing off the old furnace and commit to the sale of the new furnace.  You really don't want the customer waffling on that.

So they're right.  Fixing an old furnace usually doesn't make much sense.